# what if we use seperate tag for low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, tags

I've seen often new users' questions get into hold because of off-topic, unclear and trivia.

What if we use separate tag for those questions so we can easily find what was gone bad and ultimately try to either bring back as a good question or just remove it? There are huge number of those on hold questions are being neglected every day and they keep pushing down by other questions often with popular tagged question.

what I suggest is, that if we use a separate tag, either moderators and/or experienced users can give little bit more attention to those low quality questions and make something good out of them? it's just an idea.

Comment: Tags are not for this purpose, edits and voting are

Comment: Just search for `closed:yes`. You'll find all closed/on hold questions.

Comment: Closed questions are Deleted after , I think, 30 days or whenever the script runs.

Comment: thought that some questions may revive and they have a potential to be a good question. so if added the tag, experienced users can do something about that.thats what i meant

Comment: Most "Closed" or "On Hold" questions can't be improved by other users. They have to be improved by the OP... **that's the point** of having that status.

Comment: okay then, just a suggestion

Answer (score 4):

### I am against such tags; they would not help, and be of any practical use.

Your proposing new tags to help more experienced users fix up poor questions; but the tags *don't actually facilitate this process in any way*. We can already look for questions that are specifically on hold; all you are proposing is using *tags* as an *alternate* means to categorise them.

#### That is not what tags are for.

Tags are intended to give specific identification to a category of *expertise* that *may* be able to answer the question.

Tags that specifically only *describe* the question are also considered *meta-tags*, which are especially condemned on the Stack Exchange network.

#### How would they actually help?

Your suggesting this change as a solution to low support fixing questions; but categorising these questions *differently* does *nothing* to facilitate further improvements to the question; in contrast, it would only give users a *slightly easier* way to identify a group of questions for votes to close.

---

All in all, I feel this feature would be at-best an irrelevant addition, and at worst, a harmful addition.